# tableToGrid - Hiding existing columns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have an existing table - here is an example:

```
<table id="searchResultsTable">
<tr><th>Column ID</th><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th></tr>
<tr><td>100</td><td>Test 1</td><td>Test 2</td><td>Test 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

I call tableToGrid:

```
tableToGrid($('#searchResultsTable'), {
    caption: "Search Results",
    sortable: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    multiselect: false,
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
    }
});
```

When a user clicks on a cell I want to read the "Column ID" cell for that row but I don't want that cell to be visible.  How can I hide that "Column ID" cell so it doesn't show up for a user but is accessible via the onSelectRow event?

Let's say you have an employee database table.  The jqGrid table would look like this:

```
ID   First Name    Last Name
101  John          Doe
102  Jane          Smith
103  Bill          Tetly
```

I don't want to show the ID column but I do want to be able to access it when a user clicks a row.  I.e. if someone clicks on "Bill" I want to be able to access the Employee.id (103) in onSelectRow.

Thanks.

Comment: Please consider revising too avoid the confusion between rows and columns.

Comment: Revised - changed "column" to "cell" to be less confusing.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think I entirely understand the question but seeing as you are using jQuery, this page may be of use to you: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: The "id" variable passed to onSelectRow is the row number.  This table is generated by data from a SQL call and each row has it's own primary key.  I need to get that key when a user clicks on a row.  My thought was to add a hidden column with that key in it, but I'm having a problem trying to hide columns via colModel in a tableToGrid call.

Comment: Assuming you have control over the server side scripting and that it is PHP, add an id to the row such as `'row-' . $key` Then you can use the generated id to hide the row. Does that answer what you are asking? I'm still having trouble fully understanding the question.

Comment: I do control the server side code.  I actually want to hide the first (Column ID) column.  Let's say I have an "Employee" database table and I output it to an HTML table and call tableToGrid for it.  The first column in that table is a generated Employee.id field.  I don't want to show it, but I want to know it when the onSelectRow event is triggered.

Comment: `It looks like this.` This as in your initial question?

Comment: Modified the original question to include a better example.  Hopefully that's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source for [grid.tbltogrid.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.tbltogrid.js) you can see that it allows you to pass in the `colNames` and `colModel` options as part of the `options` parameter. For example:

```
tableToGrid($('#searchResultsTable'), {
 colNames: ... , 
 colModel: ... ,
 caption: "Search Results",
 sortable: true,
 width: 800,
 height: 400,
 multiselect: false,
 onSelectRow: function(id) {
 }
});
```

So if you can figure out what information to pass to these objects, you can specify them directly and then just add `hidden: true` to the colModel for the `ID` column.

Comment: I tried that, actually.  It had unpredictable results for some reason.  Some columns that were showing data just fine were blank when I added the colModel attribute.  Not sure why.

Comment: Hmm. The only other thing I can suggest is to use the unminified jqGrid code, and set a breakpoint inside `tableToGrid` to see what it builds for `colNames` and `colModel`. Then just use that data and see if you still get unpredictable results. Of course this assumes your HTML table header stays the same - if it does not, maybe that explains the unpredictability??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a column ID, you should add the ID attribute to the TR-tag:

```
<table id="searchResultsTable">
<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>
<tr id="100"><td>John</td><td>Doe</td></tr>
</table>
```

When the user clicks on a row, you can pick up the ID easily

Comment: I was trying this but the grid seems to be overwriting my id's with it's own that just count from 1 to however many rows I have.  Is there some option I need to specify so it will pick this up?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference.

Add an id to your th:

```
<table id="searchResultsTable">
   <tr>
      <th id="columnId">Column ID</th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td>Test 3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can hide the column using 'hideCol':

```
tableToGrid($('#searchResultsTable'), {
    caption: "Search Results",
    sortable: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    multiselect: false,
    loadComplete: function() {
      $('#searchResultsTable').hideCol("columnId");
    },
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change column width for any number of columns

In this case after the jqgrid getting build you can just go to the table getting generated and manually change all the column widths of column header and the respective data without righting some tedious code.

```
var tabColWidths ='70px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px';

    function reDefineColWidth(){
            var widthsArr = tabColWidths.split('|');

        for(var j=0; j < widthsArr.length ; j++ ){
                $('.ui-jqgrid-labels > th:eq('+j+')').css('width',widthsArr[j]);
                $('#searchResultsTable tr').find('td:eq('+j+')').each(function(){$(this).css('width',widthsArr[j]);})
            }
    }
```